# Transport.send(javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have been trying to send a feed back form details to a particular mail.I get name,email and feedbacktext from user.When he submits , in my Java class I do the following

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String feedback = request.getParameter("feedback");

System.out.println(name + "--" + email + "--" + feedback);

String to = "tester@gmail.com";

String from = email;

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

Properties properties = System.getProperties();

properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "name"); // User name
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "pass"); // password
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

// Get the default Session object.
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

response.setContentType("text/html");

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress(to));

message.setSubject("FeedBack From" + name);

message.setText(feedback);
// Send message
Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("Sent");
```

This produces an error

> at Transport.send(javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect).

What I am confused is about its not a two way mail where I need from and to ,here I just need to send the mail to tester.I know I am doing something wrong here but not able to identify it.

Comment: don't you miss some authentification? see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32331004/180100). Also note that there is a debug mode (see the manual) for javamail that could help in the diagnostic

Comment: @RC.  -  Here we cant make the user to enter his username and pass everytime. When a feed back form is entered it should directly go to the company mail. Is what  I am asking even possible or should I save it on db and then use some logic to send to the company mail

Comment: I didn't say you need to ask the user for a password, you can use an hardcoded value ("your" account), but I'm pretty sure gmail smtp is protected by authentication, see here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Using "your" account information might be fine when the application is running on your server, but not if the application is running on the user's machine.

Comment: I corrected the problem it was related with Gmail-Security